# Synonym of Synonym

Tags: synonyms

Is a synonym of a synonym a synonym of the first word?

For example: A synonym of `Charisma` is `Personality`. A synonym of `Personality` is `Character`.

Therefore, can we assume that `Charisma` and `Character` are synonyms of each other...?

Is the above a good example of when this in-direct synonym example proves to be correct?

Comment: No, because the overlap is almost never complete.

Comment: Generally speaking, it would be a poor assumption.

Comment: "Fast" means "attached".  "Quick" means "fast".  "Quick" also means "alive".  Therefore "attached" means "alive"?

Comment: Possibly, but not certainly. A synonym B of a word A is best defined as a word B which may replace A in some of its usages with no or insignificant change in meaning. But a synonym C of B may not be interchangeable with B for any of the senses which A and B have in common. // The first thing to make sure you understand is that 'synonymous' doesn't mean 'always interchangeable'.

Comment: @HotLicks, sure, but your synonyms are in different contexts.

Comment: I believe better examples could be found where the context is the same and still C would not be a synonym of A.

Comment: Would you say that 'Charisma' and 'Character' are synonyms? I'd say that someone who has charisma has character.

Comment: @MartinRand That's anecdotal evidence. In many cases - perhaps even in a majority of cases - the assumption would prove true. But it cannot be relied upon as a general rule.

Comment: I am curious though whether my synonym comparison of charisma and character is correct, as Google doesn't list them as synonyms (directly that is).

Comment: 'Untipped' and 'simple' are not synonyms, but they are both synonyms of 'plain' (though the usage of 'plain cigarettes' for 'untipped cigarettes' is rare nowadays).

Comment: There are no exact synonyms.

Comment: @MartinRand My dictionary lists *strength of character* as synonym for *charisma*. Personally, I would not say that *charisma* and *character* cannot be synonyms. However, that's still just a random example that says nothing about the rule. In fact, I would speculate that a case could be found where A is a synonym of B, but B is not a synonym of A.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, mine says the same about strength of character. Strength of character would be the same as saying someone "has character"?

Comment: @MartinRand As I said, it *could* be. But what can you infer from this? (Hint: nothing)

Comment: A person with *charisma* usually *is a character*.  Whether he/she *has character* is an entirely different question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k 'I would speculate that a case could be found where A is a synonym of B, but B is not a synonym of A.' does not make sense. Either both will work in a given setting, or only one will, or neither will. There may be the complication of polysemy-with-hypernymy (It was a hurricane [polyseme 1], but not a hurricane [polyseme 2]), where senses conflict.

Comment: I've not been able to separate _abstruse_ and _recondite_ other than by frequency of usage (and it's their semantics that decides synonymity).

Answer (score 1):

**Are charisma and character synonyms?**

Charisma means being full of character, so in some sentences yes, but that is entirely coincidental of your reasoning.

**Is every synonym of a word's synonym also a synonym of the first word?**

No. This is because not every word has the same meaning, and many words have multiple meanings. Even if a word has 15 different synonyms, not all of those words hold *exactly* the same meaning. However, in certain contexts, many words are interchangeable with one another.

*Example:* Anger and rage are synonyms, they have almost the same meaning... until anger is being used as a verb. "You anger me." makes sense but "You rage me." does not. Rage has a different forn for that function, "enrage".

Because words may have considerable overlap and contextual interchangeability, we categorize them as synonyms of each other for their individual similarities. Because not every word has exactly the same meaning, they don't perfectly overlap with the same group of words. While a synonym of a synonym *may* also be a direct synonym of the first word, it would likely already be listed as such in a thesaurus if it were.

Comment: The last sentence sums it up well, and I think you can draw a further conclusion: if a thesaurus lists B as a synonym for A, and C as a synonym for B, but it does *not* list C as a synonym for A, it's probably safe to assume that C is not, in general, a synonym for A.

Comment: @nohat, This doesn't always seem to be the case. Using my example of Charisma and Character, neither appear as synonyms of each other despite Charisma meaning "full of character/has character/a character, etc).

Comment: @Martin Rand, I've found that different thesauruses don't always list all of the same words as being synonyms. I think it varies depending on how big their budget is, size constraints for the publication, staff expertise, available resources, etc.

Comment: @MartinRand Charisma is a specific and inherently positive attribute of a person, whereas character is more general and more neutral. I don't think that charisma and character are synonyms at all. There are certain contexts where you could use either word, but that doesn't make them synonyms.